# Database class implementation

Tags: php, oop, pdo, odbc

I created a connection class which extends PDO, with methods such as modelize, get_tables, create, insert, etc... It works very well with MySQL.

Then I created a History class which extends Connection and adds CRUD history in a log file or a table each time an action is performed on the DB. They both implement an interface for all the CRUD related methods. It still works very well with MySQL.

Now, I need to work with SQLite.

I have plenty of functions in Connection which must be rewritten so I thought I could keep my Connection class, make an interface (engines) with these DB-specific functions, and develop specific classes for MySQL and SQLite which would be extending Connection.

But now if I want to use history - which has no DB specific methods... How should I do?

I wonder what would be the best way to structure these classes.

Thanks!

```
namespace bbn\db;

class connection extends \PDO implements actions, api, engines{
  public function __construct($cfg){
    ...
  }
  ...
}

interface api
{

    public function select($table, $fields, $where, $order, $limit, $start);

    public function insert($table, array $values, $ignore);

    public function insert_update($table, array $values);

    public function update($table, array $values, array $where);

    public function delete($table, array $where);

    public function insert_ignore($table, array $values);
}


interface engines
{

    public function __construct($cfg);

    public function change($db);

    public function get_full_name($table, $escaped=false);

    public function disable_keys();

    public function enable_keys();

    public function get_databases();

    public function get_tables();

    public function get_columns($table);

    public function get_keys($table);

    public function get_create($table);

    public function get_delete($table, array $where);

    public function get_select($table, array $fields = array(), array $where = array(), $order, $limit, $start, $php = false);

    public function get_insert($table, array $fields = array(), $ignore = false, $php = false);

    public function get_update($table, array $fields = array(), array $where = array(), $php = false);

    public function create_db_index($table, $column);

    public function delete_db_index($table, $column);

}

class history extends connection implements api
{
    ...
}

class mysql extends connection implements engines
{
  ...
}

class sqlite extends connection implements engines
{
  ...
}
```

If you wonder the "actions" interface is implented by another class extending PDOStatement (but it has nothing to do with my issue)

Comment: That's formidable task - to rewrite SQL in PHP. I wish you good luck with it

Comment: @Your Common Sense: Maybe you can just forget about the whole mockable database ambition and focus on the class structure problem :)

Comment: I think the best thing would be to inject a connection into the `history` object and not extends `history` from `connection`. So you have a method `setConnection($connection)` in the history object and work with that.

Comment: @redreggae: Thanks, but I inject it and then use the same methods? Because the idea in history is that the constructor is different, but while you use seemlessly the usual connection methods it writes a history of the changes.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question however I would suggest that when you rewrite the api interface you use a dialect of SQL (perhaps SQL-92?) that will be likely to be implemented by both MySQL and SQLite (and probably other database engines since you never know when you'll need to work with Oracle, DB2, etc.). For instance "LIMIT" and "BEGIN" are extensions to SQL and won't work on other databases.

Comment: what about triggers? sqlite also support triggers. triggers would be the best way to save actions to history table. another alternative is to dispatch an event on every db action. With events you could make the history class fully independent.

Comment: @Benny Hill: Good point, but actually I write the SQL of my methods in the engine specific classes, so I can stay specific! But with my little knowledge of other ODBCs I didn't know LIMIT was specific...

Comment: @redreggae: I have been thinking about triggers. The problem now is that I have to do an import of a very old and very big mysql DB and as they had a log of the changes I have to recreate the whole history. So I need to go through PHP to get the time and the user, and I need anyway this way of being able to "antidate" the history if needed. I wouldn't know how to achieve that with triggers.